# Contour plot with function receiving lists

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I have some function `f(list)` with receives as argument a list with length 2, i.e., list = [entry_1, entry_2]. I need to do a contour plot of this function:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000+1)
y = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000+1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = ?
plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

The problem is: I don't know how to pass the arguments. If the function was of the type f(x,y), then

```
Z = f(X, Y)
```

would do the job. But

```
Z = f([X,Y])
```

fails: it receives too many arguments. How can I do this?

EDIT: Here are the functions of the program:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def c_Gamma_gamma_fv(cf, cv):
    return np.abs((4 * eta_gamma * charges**2 * a_q * cf).sum() + 4.* cf *a_tau/3. + a_w * cv)**2/Gamma_gamma

def mu_fv(cf, cv):
    return np.array([cf**4,
                     cf**2 * cv**2,
                     cf**2 * c_Gamma_gamma_fv(cf, cv),
                     cv**2 * c_Gamma_gamma_fv(cf, cv),
                     cf**4,
                     cv**2 * cf**2,
                     cf**2 * cv**2,
                     cv**4,
                     cv**2 * cf**2,
                     cv**4])

def chi_square_fv(clist):
    cf, cv = clist
    return ((mu_fv(cf, cv) - mu_data) @ inv_cov @ (mu_fv(cf, cv) - mu_data))

x0 = [1., 1.]
res_fv = minimize(chi_square_fv, x0)
print(res_fv)

def delta_chi_fv(clist):
    return chi_square_fv(clist) - chi_square_fv([res_fv.x[0], res_fv.x[1]])
```

All variables not explicit are constants. The function I want to plot is delta_chi_fv.

Comment: Can you paste all your traceback information when you got ?

Comment: Give us more information about the function.

Comment: This line fails: `res_fv = minimize(chi_square_fv, x0)`.  `minimize` is not defined.  `chi_square_fv([X,Y])` runs fine until it hits undefined variables.

Comment: right, i forgot it: `from scipy.optimize import minimize`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found (with a little help of a professor here in my university), though not the fastest one, works:

```
Z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        z = delta_chi_fv([x[i], y[j]])
        Z[i,j] = z
```

With this construction of Z, then

```
plt.contour(X,Y,Z)
```

works fine. If anyone knows another answer, it would be great to learn more things about this language.

Cheers,
Gabriel.